# cordova camera plugin asks permission every time

Tags: android, cordova, camera, gallery

I'm using

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

to access the gallery of the user.
however the plugin makes the app ask for permission everytime.
while testing it on my phone, even though i granted permission once the plugin keeps asking for permission everytime i call the

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
  cameraSuccess,
  cameraError,
    {
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    }
);
```

also if i deny the permission the second time the APP crashes.

Comment: May be you have `compiled SDK version` with **`Android 6.0`** in your app. I heard some plugins to be work with this which allow you to hit runtime permissions in cordova.

Comment: @jamian Use latest version of camera plugin to arrest permissions related issues in android marshmallow

Comment: remove existing plugin
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera
Add new one
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1

Comment: @Ramakrishna your technique worked. Thanks

Comment: Accept my answer @jamian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature to persist granted permission was missing on earlier versions of the plugin. This is fixed with the most recent release (at the time of writing it's rel/2.4.0).

1) Uninstall the the current plugin and then...

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera
```

2) ... install the latest version of it.

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera rel/2.4.0`